# How to replace all numbers with hyphens in the string?

Tags: php, regex

I explain my question by one  example:

**Example:**

*(English version)*

```
$str = '1 healthy, fine, sound 2 tip-top, fit, robust, sturdy & 1  substandard, poor';
```

I want this output:

```
- healthy, fine, sound
- tip-top, fit, robust, sturdy
&
- substandard, poor
```

*(Persian version)* - It starts from the right

```
$str ='1 خشكاندن، خشكانيدن 2رطوبتزدايي كردن، نمزدايي كردن & تر کردن';
```

I want this output:

```
- خشكاندن، خشكانيدن
- رطوبتزدايي كردن، نمزدايي كردن
&
تر کردن
```

I know, `1` in this example is really vague. But actually it is the first character in the right. But in SO, because there isn't a proper direction for Persian, `1` goes in the left.

---

**Note:** Perhaps there are no numbers or even no `&`. In this case I don't want any change ..!

```
$str = 'healthy, fine, sound, tip-top'; // I want this: healthy, fine, sound, tip-top


$str = 'healthy, fine, sound & poor'; /* I want this: healthy, fine, sound
                                                      &
                                                       poor
                                      */
```

I can do that using multiple `str_replace()`. But I want to know, is it possible to I do that using REGEX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script works for both the English & the Persian variant.

```
$str = "1 خشكاندن، خشكانيدن 2رطوبتزدايي كردن، نمزدايي كردن & تر کردن";
// $str = '1 healthy, fine, sound 2 tip-top, fit, robust, sturdy & 1  substandard, poor';
$dashed_line = preg_replace("/[0-9]+/", "- ", $str);
$lines = preg_replace("/(?<!^)- /", "\n- ", $dashed_line);
$lines_with_and = preg_replace("/&/", "\n&\n", $lines);
$lines_with_and_single_space = preg_replace("/ +/", " ", $lines_with_and);
echo preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $lines_with_and_single_space);
```

Comment: Your solution is fine. +1. Just there is a small problem. [line 9](https://3v4l.org/kJ0iM)

Comment: Just remove the actual newline (enter) from your string. In other words, define your variable $str in a single line.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested the Persian variant as I have no experience with RTL scripts, but it should work for the English example.

```
// first let's put all the numbers to a new line
$digit_split_str = preg_replace('/(?<!^)(?=\d)/', "\n", $str);
// then ampersands
$ampersand_split_str = preg_replace('/(?<!^)&/', "\n&\n", $digit_split_str);
// then let's replace the numbers at the start of the string with dashes
$dashed_str = preg_replace('/^\d+/m', "- ", $ampersand_split_str);
```

EDIT: fixed corner cases around ampersands and newlines...

Comment: Well, According to what I tested and as you mentioned, it doesn't work for Persian context. I haven't tested it for English so far. But for Persian, it cuts the string from somewhere ...!

Comment: I can't help you with that, my editor can't handle RTL input.